# Mouse coordinates appears to incorrectly place Raphael.js objects

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I have some rect's on a Raphael space. I set up a quick mouse coordinate display for precise placement of objects:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){

        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;

    document.getElementById('position').innerHTML = " X = "+ x +" Y = "+ y;

            });
```

However, it seems that the rect's tend to be about 10px too far of where it is intended to be. Why is this so? (Also I know using `style` instead of a css file is bad practice but I just wanted to jump straight into toying with Raphael and not worry about that)

```js
var p = Raphael("paper");
let r1, r2, r3, l1;


r1 = p.rect(200, 200, 40, 40)
  .attr({
    'fill': 'red',
    'cursor': 'pointer',
    'href': 'https://www.google.com/',
  });
r2 = p.rect(277, 320, 50, 50)
  .attr({
    'fill': 'blue',
    'cursor': 'pointer',
    'href': 'https://www.google.com/',
  });
p.path("M 200,200 L 240,240");


r3 = p.rect(377, 300, 30, 80)
  .attr({
    'fill': 'yellow',
    'cursor': 'pointer',
    'href': 'https://www.google.com/',
  });




document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {

  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;

  document.getElementById('position').innerHTML = " X = " + x + " Y = " + y;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>tester2</title>
  <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="paper"></div>
  </div>
  <p id="position">Test</p>
  <style>
    #paper {
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

I suspect that my mouse coordinate system is simply off, but if so I do not know how to configure it relative to `Raphael("paper");`

Live link to problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/oLwydha6/

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total difference is *9px*, margin from the body (*8px*) and border (*1px*). You might want to consider using [`offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) instead of [`clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX) to get the positions:

```js
var p = Raphael("paper");
let r1, r2, r3, l1;


r1 = p.rect(200, 200, 40, 40)
  .attr({
    'fill': 'red',
    'cursor': 'pointer',
    'href': 'https://www.google.com/',
  });
r2 = p.rect(277, 320, 50, 50)
  .attr({
    'fill': 'blue',
    'cursor': 'pointer',
    'href': 'https://www.google.com/',
  });
p.path("M 200,200 L 240,240");


r3 = p.rect(377, 300, 30, 80)
  .attr({
    'fill': 'yellow',
    'cursor': 'pointer',
    'href': 'https://www.google.com/',
  });

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {

  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  document.getElementById('position').innerHTML = " clientX = " + x + " clientY = " + y;
  document.getElementById('position_offset').innerHTML = " offsetX = " + event.offsetX + " offsetY = " + event.offsetY;
});
```

```css
#paper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.8/raphael.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="paper"></div>
</div>
<p id="position">Test</p>
<p id="position_offset">Test</p>
<h1 id="h1">hello world</h1>
```